# Prove the Leibniz formula for Determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, determinant

I am trying to prove that if $A \in M_{n\times n}(F)$, then

$$\det(A)=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^n a_{i \sigma(i)}\tag 1$$

The question asks me to use the following theorem:

> If $\delta: M_{n×n}(F) → F$ is an alternating $n-$linear function
> such that $\delta(I) = 1$, then $\delta(A) = \det(A)$ for every $A ∈ M_{n×n}(F)$.

The way I am interpreting the question is that I need to show that it satisfies the multilinear (n-linear), alternating, and normalized properties (the formula maps the identity matrix to 1) of the determinant.

Then the second part of the question asks to show that if a single column of A is completely comprised of $0$'s, then $\det(A)=0$. I feel that the solution to second part of the question should be clearer after solving for the first part.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Presumably the second line should be $\det A = \sum\dots$. Which part of verifying that it's multilinear and alternating is troubling you?

For the normalised property and the second part, here's a hint: $\prod_{i=1}^n a_{i,\sigma(i)}$ can't contain more than one entry from the same row or the same column.